# Is there a way to export object level data from Google Analytics? What is the lowest level of granularity available in GA?

Tags: google-analytics

I am exporting site traffic data from Google Analytics but it looks like the lowest level of granularity is by minute. So that means data will be aggregated by minutes. Is it possible to export data by user or by page etc. instead of by date time.

Eg: How do I tie a user visit to a ppc ad click?
How to track all the activity by a given user?

Comment: You don't, usually. GA reports aggregated data. You can store a id per user in a custom dimension (be mindful of the Google TOS - you must not store data that identifies a person), but reporting on single users is not what GA is good at and if you need that you should look for other tools. Plus, since this is not about code it's probably off-topic.

Comment: You can do this with Scitylana - [www.scitylana.com](https://www.scitylana.com) Data is extracted into .txt files daily - all clicks from all visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only can get session and hit level data using Google Analytics Premium and it's BigQuery Export feature. Take a look: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618

To do this using Google Analytics Standard (Free) and Core Reporting you will need  to implement a lot of custom tags to your site/app with and to be very specific on your API queries. However it can work, It will require a lot of api requests to get data out and for sure it will be such a kludge.